# Control vibration of Android

Tags: android, audio, shake, vibration

I use this code to set vibration:

```
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
v.vibrate(500);
```

I want set vibration only when the sound of phone is enable, but so the shake is always enable.

There is a method to check the sound's state? So i can inhibit the vibration when the sound's state of the phone is set in silent mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

switch (audioManager.getRingerMode()) {
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
        //Logic
        break;
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
         //Logic
        break;
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
         //Logic
        break;
}
```

Try this

Comment: Sure! I'm sorry I had to wait a limit of 5 minutes to accept. Thanks again!